# Java: Disable all JToggleButtons after Submission — setEnabled(false);

Tags: java, swing, jtogglebutton

I am currently developing a booking system as a task for my degree. What would be the best way to disable selected JToggleButtons after a button is pressed; so seats wouldn't be available after purchase. I have tried using for loops and arrays but have had some trouble retrieving which button has been pressed. Here's my code, please run it if you can you will understand it better.

PS: I'm not making use of a database.

Thank you.

```
// CM1203 Fundamentals of Computing with Java; Second Assignement.
// Walter Carvalho - C1001984; 2012.
// Cardiff University

// Load Libraries
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class cinemaSystem extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    // Global Variables
    boolean lselected, rselected, mselected;
    double chargeDue;
    int a, b, c;
    static Ticket oapticket, childticket, adultticket;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(); // Creates JFrame
    JLabel title, lchild, ladult, loap, ltotalprice, time;
    JTextField child, adult, oap, totalprice;
    JButton submit;
    JRadioButton time1, time2, time3, time4, time5; // Radio Butons
    JToggleButton l[][], m[][], r[][]; // Names grid of JButtons
    JPanel panel1, panel2, panel3, panel4, panel5, panel6;
    ArrayList<String> seatsAvailable = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> coupon = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Constructor
    public cinemaSystem(){

            title = new JLabel("Cinema Booking System");
            title.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 30));
            title.setLocation(12,5);
            title.setSize(600, 60);

            frame.setLayout(null); // Setting Grid Layout
            // panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(seat,row));
            l = new JToggleButton[4][4]; // Allocating Size of Grid
            panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,4));
            panel1.setBounds(20, 95, 220, 140);
            for(int y = 0; y <4 ; y++){
                    for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++){
                        l[x][y] = new JToggleButton("L" + y + x); // Creates New JButton
                        l[x][y].addActionListener(this);
                        seatsAvailable.add("L" + y + x);
                        panel1.add(l[x][y]); //adds button to grid
                    }
            }

            m = new JToggleButton[4][2]; // Allocating Size of Grid
            panel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,4));
            panel2.setBounds(240, 165, 220, 70);
            for(int y = 0; y <2 ; y++){
                    for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++){
                        m[x][y] = new JToggleButton("M" + y + x); // Creates New JButton
                        m[x][y].addActionListener(this);
                        seatsAvailable.add("M" + y + x);
                        panel2.add(m[x][y]); //adds button to grid
                    }
            }

            r = new JToggleButton[4][4]; // Allocating Size of Grid
            panel3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,4));
            panel3.setBounds(460, 95, 220, 140);
            for(int y = 0; y <4 ; y++){
                    for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++){
                        r[x][y] = new JToggleButton("R" + y + x); // Creates New JButton
                        r[x][y].addActionListener(this);
                        seatsAvailable.add("R" + y + x);
                        panel3.add(r[x][y]); //adds button to grid
                    }
            }

            panel4 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
            panel4.setBounds(0, 250, 300, 70);

            lchild = new JLabel("Child");
            child = new JTextField("0", 2);
            child.addActionListener(this);

            ladult = new JLabel("Adult");
            adult = new JTextField("0", 2);
            adult.addActionListener(this);

            loap = new JLabel("OAP");
            oap = new JTextField("0", 2);
            oap.addActionListener(this);

            submit = new JButton("Submit");
            submit.addActionListener(this);

            oapticket = new Ticket(4.70);
            childticket = new Ticket(3.50);
            adultticket = new Ticket(6.10);     

            child.addKeyListener(new MyKeyAdapter());
            oap.addKeyListener(new MyKeyAdapter());
            adult.addKeyListener(new MyKeyAdapter());

            panel4.add(lchild);
            panel4.add(child);
            panel4.add(ladult);
            panel4.add(adult);
            panel4.add(loap);
            panel4.add(oap);
            panel4.add(submit);

            panel5 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
            panel5.setBounds(240, 250, 300, 70);

            ltotalprice = new JLabel("Charge Due (£): ");
            totalprice = new JTextField("£0.00", 5);
            totalprice.setEnabled(false);
            panel5.add(ltotalprice);
            panel5.add(totalprice);

            panel6 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
            panel6.setBounds(0, 55, 560, 30);

            time = new JLabel("Please select a film time: ");
            time1 = new JRadioButton("13:00", true);
            time2 = new JRadioButton("15:00", false);
            time3 = new JRadioButton("17:00", false);
            time4 = new JRadioButton("19:00", false);
            time5 = new JRadioButton("21:00", false);

            ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
            group.add(time1);
            group.add(time2);
            group.add(time3);
            group.add(time4);
            group.add(time5);
            panel6.add(time);
            panel6.add(time1);
            panel6.add(time2);
            panel6.add(time3);
            panel6.add(time4);
            panel6.add(time5);
            time1.addActionListener(this);
            time2.addActionListener(this);
            time3.addActionListener(this);
            time4.addActionListener(this);
            time5.addActionListener(this);
            frame.add(title);
            frame.add(panel1);
            frame.add(panel2);
            frame.add(panel3);
            frame.add(panel4);
            frame.add(panel5);
            frame.add(panel6);
            frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 350));
            frame.setTitle("Cinema Booking");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack(); //sets appropriate size for frame
            frame.setVisible(true); //makes frame visible


    }

    // Calculates Charge Due for current transaction.
    public double calcChargeDue(){
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        double chargeDue = 0.0;
        chargeDue = (a*childticket.price) + (b*oapticket.price) + (c*adultticket.price);
        totalprice.setText("£"+df.format(chargeDue));
        return chargeDue;
    }

    // Method to check if the number of people matches the number of seats selected.
    public void check(){
        int check = coupon.size();
        int noTickets = a + b + c;
        if (check != noTickets){
            submit.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else {
            submit.setEnabled(true);
        }

    }

    // Ticket Object
    public class Ticket {

        double price;

        // Constructor
        public Ticket(double cost) {
            price = cost;
        }

        public double getTicketPrice() {
            return price;
        }

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        a = Integer.parseInt(child.getText());
        b = Integer.parseInt(oap.getText());
        c = Integer.parseInt(adult.getText());

        for(int y = 0; y < 4; y++){
            for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++){

                lselected = l[x][y].isSelected();
                rselected = r[x][y].isSelected();

                if (e.getSource() == l[x][y]) {
                    if(lselected == true){
                        coupon.add(e.getActionCommand());
                        calcChargeDue();
                        check();
                    }
                    else {
                        coupon.remove(e.getActionCommand());
                        check();
                    }
                }

                if (e.getSource() == r[x][y]) {
                    if(rselected == true){
                        coupon.add(e.getActionCommand());
                        calcChargeDue();
                        check();
                    }
                    else {
                        coupon.remove(e.getActionCommand());
                        check();
                    }
                }

                if (e.getSource() == oap){
                    calcChargeDue();
                    check();
                }

                if (e.getSource() == adult){
                    calcChargeDue();
                    check();
                }

                if (e.getSource() == child){
                    calcChargeDue();
                    check();
                }

            }
        }

        for(int y = 0; y < 2; y++){
            for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++){

                mselected = m[x][y].isSelected();

                if (e.getSource() == m[x][y]) {
                    if(mselected == true){
                        coupon.add(e.getActionCommand());
                        calcChargeDue();
                        check();
                    }
                    else {
                        coupon.remove(e.getActionCommand());
                        check();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(time1 == e.getSource()){

        }

        if(time2 == e.getSource()){

        }

        if(time3 == e.getSource()){

        }

        if(time4 == e.getSource()){

        }

        if(time5 == e.getSource()){

        }

        if(submit == e.getSource()) {

            for(int y = 0; y < 4; y++){
                for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++){

                    lselected = l[x][y].isSelected();
                    rselected = r[x][y].isSelected();

                    if (lselected == true) {
                            l[x][y].setEnabled(false);
                    }

                    if (rselected == true) {
                            r[x][y].setEnabled(false);
                    }

                }
            }

            for(int y = 0; y < 2; y++){
                for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++){

                    mselected = m[x][y].isSelected();

                    if (mselected == true) {
                            m[x][y].setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            }

            Collections.sort(coupon);
            System.out.println("Here's your ticket:");
            System.out.println(coupon);
            System.out.println("Child: " + child.getText());
            System.out.println("Adult: " + adult.getText());
            System.out.println("OAP: " + oap.getText());
            System.out.println("Total Price: " + totalprice.getText());
            System.out.println("Thank you. Enjoy your film.");
            System.out.println(" ");
            coupon.clear();
            child.setText("0");
            adult.setText("0");
            oap.setText("0");
        }

    }

    // Main Class
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            new cinemaSystem(); //makes new ButtonGrid with 2 parameters
    }
}
```

Related: [Multiple Bookings System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094558/java-multiple-bookings-system)

Comment: Looks like you forgot to paste your code in your question.

Comment: for better help sooner edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Added the code for him from another question. Maybe he couldn't figure out how to edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use a `List<AbstractButton>` or an array and then loop through the list or array checking to see for which buttons `isSelected()` returns true.

For better help, though, post your code.